# swiftmailer error since update to php7

Tags: php, smtp, swiftmailer

I have a strange Problem whit Swiftmailer sending mails over SMTP. Since the Update to PHP 7.0.14 there is an error.

```
Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""
```

This error appears sporadically. Around every 10-50 times the server tries to send a mail.  Sometimes comes 10 times in a row.  A parallel Web-server still running on PHP 5 doesn’t have this Issue. So I'm relative sure that it is not the SMTP-Sever. Swiftmailer was updated to the current version to be sure that it is not a fixed bug on this part.

Dos someone knows this behaviour?

Comment: I have the same Issue with PHP 7.1.6. Do you have any Solution yet?

Comment: I tried hard.. but I changed back to phpmailer. It works fine with PHP7.